# Why do we use additional semaphore in Producer-Consumer in C

Tags: c, multithreading

> 

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore>

sem_t empty, full, mutex;
#define N 10

void* producerThread(void*) {
    int i = 0;

    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&empty);
        sem_wait(&mutex);

        buff[i] = rand();
        i = ++i % N;

        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&full);
    }
}

void* consumerThread(void*) {
    int i = 0;

    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&full);
        sem_wait(&mutex);

        printf("%d\n", buff[i]);
        i = ++i % N;

        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&empty);
    }
}

void main() {
    pthread_t producer, consumer;

    sem_init(&empty, N);
    sem_init(&full, 0);
    sem_init(&mutex, 1);

    pthread_create(&producer, NULL, &producerThread, NULL);
    pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, &consumerThread, NULL);

    pthread_join(producer, NULL);
    pthread_join(consumer, NULL);

    sem_destroy(&empty);
    sem_destroy(&full);
    sem_destroy(&mutex);
}
```

> I have the following question, this code is well know Producer-Consumer problem when learning about multi-threading, but i do not understand why do we need an additional semaphore (mutex) in this case? Can't we do everything with semaphores full & empty and there will be no problems whatsoever where producer produces on the spot consumer didnt already consume or vice-versa? Afaik with mutex we are adding additional bagage on the code and this is not necessary. Can someone point to me why we need 3 semaphores instead of 2?

> I've tried running this code on my computer and everything works the same with and without additional semaphore, so I do not understand why did author choose 3 semaphores in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `empty` and `full` semaphores take values in the range [0..N), allowing the producer to run ahead of the consumer by up to N elements.

The `mutex` semaphore only bounces between values 0 and 1, and enforces a critical section ensuring that only one thread is touching any part of the buffer memory at a time. However, the separate computation of `i` on each thread and the `empty`/`full` handshake ensures there can be no data race on individual elements of `buff`, so that critical section is *probably* overkill.

You don't show the definition of `buff`. For a sufficiently narrow datatype (like individual bytes), some architectures may exhibit [word tearing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6) on concurrent writes to adjacent elements. However in your example only one thread is performing writes, so even in the presence of word-tearing the concurrent adjacent reads are unlikely to observe a problem.